# Getting response code from google drive api?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to google drive using PHP code. I can't get API response whatever it is. Incase of successful upload response should be 200 and different error codes. I just want to get receive error codes. Can anyone help me with it. Bellow I have pasted my complete code. I am using function like check if folder already exists and if it does place file in it otherwise just create new folder and place file in it. I am trying to make my code fail safe, if an error is encountered it saves the particular file and error code. right now it is just returning critical error and breaks AJAX.

```
function getClient(){

    $authdata = array (
        'web' => 
            array (
            'client_id' => get_option("csc_gdrive_clientid"),
            'project_id' => get_option("csc_gdrive_projectid"),
            'auth_uri' => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            'token_uri' => "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            'auth_provider_x509_cert_url' => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
            'client_secret' => get_option("csc_gdrive_clientsecret"), 
        ),
    );

    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../vendor/autoload.php');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAuthConfig($authdata);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    // $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
    $client->setRedirectUri(get_option("csc_gdrive_redirecturi"));

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file key_config.txt stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'111key_config.txt';
    
    if (!file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        return;
    } else{
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)){   
        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                
                $authCode = get_option('csc_gdrive_token');
                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
return $client;
}enter code here


function create_folder( $folder_name, $parent_folder_id=null ){
    
    //$folder_list = $this->check_folder_exists( $folder_name );
    // if folder does not exists
    //if( count( $folder_list ) == 0 ){
    $client = $this->getClient();
    if($client){
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );
        $folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $folder->setName( $folder_name );
        $folder->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
        if( !empty( $parent_folder_id ) ){
            $folder->setParents( [ $parent_folder_id ] );        
        }
        $result = $service->files->create( $folder );
        $folder_id = null;
        if( isset( $result['id'] ) && !empty( $result['id'] ) ){
            $folder_id = $result['id'];
        }
        return $folder_id;
    }
    //}
    //return $folder_list[0]['id'];
}

// This will check folders and sub folders by name
function check_folder_exists( $folder_name, $parent_folder_id=null){

    $client = $this->getClient();
    if($client){    
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );

        if ($parent_folder_id){
        
            $parameters['q'] = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='$folder_name' and trashed=false and '$parent_folder_id' in parents";
        } else {
            
            $parameters['q'] = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='$folder_name' and trashed=false";
        }
        $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
        $op = [];
        foreach( $files as $k => $file ){
            $op[] = $file;
        }
        return $op;
    }
}

// This will insert file into drive and returns boolean values.
function insert_file_to_drive( $file_path, $file_name, $parent_file_id = null ){
    $client = $this->getClient();
    if($client){
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setName( $file_name );
        if( !empty( $parent_file_id ) ){
            $file->setParents( [ $parent_file_id ] );        
        }
    
        $result = $service->files->create(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path.'/'.$file_name),
                'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
            )
        );
        $is_success = false;
        if( isset( $result['name'] ) && !empty( $result['name'] ) ){
            $is_success = true;
        }
        return $is_success;
    }

}
```

Comment: normally the Google classes will throw exceptions if the API requests don't succeed.

Comment: The `try {  } catch(Exception $e) {  }` code is your new friend! Put the code that is throwing the errors inside the try. You can read about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php